# I can't use the backreference $1 in .htaccess

Tags: apache, xampp

Without using it, the redirection works fine, but I need '$1' to access the part of the url after "media".
The same problem happens when I use %{REQUEST_URI}.
%1 pass but returns nothing.

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^.*media(.*)$ /project/file.php?v=$1
```

**Error:**

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the same problem, mine was because the url has special characters so using the flag [B] to escape them resolved this problem.

```
RewriteRule ^.*media(.*)$ /project/file.php?v=$1 [B]
```